(InfluxDB + SQL) How to count number of events in a time window using date_bin, and fill empty windows with zero?
(Using InfluxDB 3.0 cloud serverless, and SQL as the query language).
I have a simple table that captures that a named event occurred (with no data attached to it). I simply want to count the number of occurrences in a given time window. I can do that using the date_bin function. However, my problem is that if no events occurred within a certain time window, no records are present in the result set.
Instead, I want the result set to include rows for every time window in the overall time range, and show 0 if no events occurred within it.
Here's my current query:
SELECT date_bin('1 minute', time) AS time, Count("Event")
FROM "CW" 
WHERE $__timeFilter(time) 
AND "Event" = 'thing_xyz_happened'
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY "time"

So for example, consider my overall query time range being 5 minutes. In the first minute, 1 "thing_xyz_happened" event occurred, and in the second minute, it happened twice. In minutes 3, 4 and 5, no such event happened and therefore no records exist in the database for those minutes. Currently here is what that query returns:



Time
Count




2024-06-03 13:37
1


2024-06-03 13:38
2



Note that 13:39, :40 and :41 are absent. This messes up my bar chart graphs. I want to show an actual "0" for those last 3 minutes:



Time
Count




2024-06-03 13:37
1


2024-06-03 13:38
2


2024-06-03 13:39
0


2024-06-03 13:40
0


2024-06-03 13:41
0



I've looked at date_bin_gapfill, but the only options available are interpolation or carrying-forward of previous data. Neither of those will give me the 0 I want.

try with generate_series function:
WITH time_series AS (
  SELECT generate_series(start_time, end_time, 1m) AS time
  FROM (
    SELECT date_trunc('minute', $__timeFrom()) AS start_time,
           date_trunc('minute', $__timeTo()) AS end_time
  )
)
SELECT date_bin('1 minute', ts.time) AS time,
       COUNT("Event") AS count
FROM time_series ts
LEFT JOIN "CW" c ON date_bin('1 minute', c.time) = date_bin('1 minute', ts.time) AND c."Event" = 'thing_xyz_happened'
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY time;


Yes, that worked (after removing the FILL (0) line). I'm not sure of the InfluxDB documentation was misleading or if I just read it wrong, but I was under the impression that the only functions that could be used with date_bin_gapfill was interpolate or locf. You found a secret alternate! https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/cloud-dedicated/query-data/sql/fill-gaps/

As per @player0's 2nd option, this is what worked:
SELECT date_bin_gapfill('1 minute', time) AS time, COALESCE(Count("Event"), 0) AS COUNT
FROM "CW" 
WHERE $__timeFilter(time) 
AND "Event" = 'thing_xyz_happened'
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY "time"

